# Is is possible to send MyTrack map uploads to Gogle.ca rather than Google.com?

Tags: google-maps

I do most of my googling in Google.ca.  Is there a way to send MyTrack map uploads to Google.ca mymaps rather than Google.com mymaps?

Answer (score 1):

My Maps should be bound to your account only. Even if you upload them to Google.com, they will still go to the same servers as Google.ca, and should show up in your account either way. Is there any particular reason you want this?